# Build vertical menu with sub-menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building my own vertical menu in CSS3 & HTML5:
[image]

I'm need devide first "item 1" into two buttons, the first is still "Item 1", the second is a arrow button, that will open/close hidden ul with sub-items. Something like that:
[image]

1st button - calls default action choosen from sub-tems.
2nd buton - gaves to user make own choose, what do now or what do always when 1st button pressed.

How I can devide the first item into two that buttons?

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <link href="./css/WMenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="WMenu">
        <li id="" class="WButton">
            Item 1
        </li>
        <ul for="AddPageBtn" class="WMenuPopup">
            <li class="WButton">Sub-Item 1</li>
            <li class="WButton">Sub-Item 2</li>
            <li class="WButton">Sub-Item 3</li>
            <li class="WButton">Sub-Item 4</li> 
        </ul>
        <li class="WButton">Item 2</li>
        <li class="WButton">Item 3</li>
        <li class="WButton">Item 4</li>
    </ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
.WMenu {
    background: url("../images/WMenu/bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-z;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

/*Выпадающее под-меню */
.WMenuPopup {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.WButton {
    background: #feffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #feffff 0%, #ddf1f9 35%, #a0d8ef 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#feffff), color-stop(35%,#ddf1f9), color-stop(100%,#a0d8ef));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 35%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 35%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 35%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 35%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#feffff', endColorstr='#a0d8ef',GradientType=0 );
    padding: 4px; 
    margin-right: 2px; 
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.WButton:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #87e0fd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#87e0fd), color-stop(40%,#53cbf1), color-stop(100%,#05abe0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#05abe0',GradientType=0 );
    padding: 4px; 
    margin-right: 2px; 
    margin-bottom: 2px; 
    font-weight:bold;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: add button html in the `li`, style to suit ...done!

Comment: You could add a button, span, div, ul li to item one, style it and do whatever you really wanted to it from there

Comment: @AlexLL Could I please have you consider my answer instead since it's a more valid way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

http://jsfiddle.net/c5JG6/

new html:

```
 <ul class="WMenu">
        <li id="" class="split_button button_left WButton">
        Item 1           
    </li>
    <li class="split_button button_right WButton">
        click!
    </li>
    <ul for="AddPageBtn" class="WMenuPopup">
        <li class="WButton">Sub-Item 1</li>
        <li class="WButton">Sub-Item 2</li>
         <li class="WButton">Sub-Item 3</li>
        <li class="WButton">Sub-Item 4</li> 
    </ul>
      <li class="WButton">Item 2</li>
      <li class="WButton">Item 3</li>
       <li class="WButton">Item 4</li>
    </ul>
```

new css:

```
 .split_button {
    display: block;
   margin-left: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px !important;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   float: left;     
}
.split_button.button_left {
   width: 80%;
} 
.split_button.button_right {
   width: 20%;
   border-left: 1px solid black;
}
.WMenuPopup {
   list-style-type: none;
   clear:both;float:none;
}
```

Will work in all browser past ie8

Comment: Actually, this isn't proper valid HTML markup and the fiddle bugs when you hover the right "click" button.

Comment: That's true, to be valid mark up the <ul> should be inside of an <li> tag. I was demonstrating how you could get two "buttons" next to eachother

Comment: Exactly and I don't think using a sibling `<li>` as the right button is the best way. Please see my updated answer with a fully functioning JSFiddle. (And without testing, I think mine would work in IE8 as well. Obviously not the gradients, but the rest.)

Comment: @JonathanCrowe, I've updates fiddle CSS to prevent auto-width for hovered elements. Also tried to make sub-items collapsible.

Answer (score 0):

First, the submenu ui should go in the parent li element. Second, just put a `<span>` or `<a>`in the li element as well, then style it.

http://jsfiddle.net/EjzuK/

**HMTL**

```
<ul class="WMenu">
    <li id="" class="WButton">
        <a>Item 1<span class="WButtonArrow">Click</span></a>
        <ul for="AddPageBtn" class="WMenuPopup">
            <li class="WButton"><a>Sub-Item 1</a></li>
            <li class="WButton"><a>Sub-Item 2</a></li>
            <li class="WButton"><a>Sub-Item 3</a></li>
            <li class="WButton"><a>Sub-Item 4</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="WButton"><a>Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="WButton"><a>Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="WButton"><a>Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.WMenu {
    background: url("../images/WMenu/bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-z;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

/*Выпадающее под-меню */
.WMenuPopup {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.WButton a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #feffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #feffff 0%, #ddf1f9 35%, #a0d8ef 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#feffff), color-stop(35%,#ddf1f9), color-stop(100%,#a0d8ef));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 35%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 35%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 35%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 35%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#feffff', endColorstr='#a0d8ef',GradientType=0 );
    padding: 4px; 
    margin-right: 2px; 
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.WButton a span.WButtonArrow {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #feffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #feffff 0%, #ddf1f9 35%, #a0d8ef 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#feffff), color-stop(35%,#ddf1f9), color-stop(100%,#a0d8ef));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 35%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 35%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 35%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 35%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#feffff', endColorstr='#a0d8ef',GradientType=0 );
    border-left: 1px solid #a0d8ef;
    padding: 4px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.WButton a span.WButtonArrow:hover {
    background: #87e0fd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#87e0fd), color-stop(40%,#53cbf1), color-stop(100%,#05abe0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#05abe0',GradientType=0 );
    border-left: 1px solid #05abe0;
}

.WButton a:hover {
    background: #87e0fd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#87e0fd), color-stop(40%,#53cbf1), color-stop(100%,#05abe0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#05abe0',GradientType=0 );
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

    $('.WButtonArrow').click(function() {

        $(this).closest('.WButton').find('.WMenuPopup').toggle();

    });

});
```

Comment: Yes It works too. But "Items 1" stay selected when "Click" is focused. In first answer I didn't found this problem. Why @ didn't works?

Comment: @AlexLL Well of course, since "Click" is a child of "Item 1", "Item 1" stay hovered when you hover it's child "Click". As you would expect in this kind of menu. As you're clicking "Click" to expand "Item 1"s submenu this would make sense and be a proper behavior, I think. And as Jonathan actually admitted, the `<ul>` submenu element should be inside the "Item 1" `<li>` element to be properly valid.

Comment: Yep, but it still functional like one button. I've updated your fiddle. Why I can't use @ for your name?